Is this assumption about a vortex's angular velocity reasonable?
I am deriving a velocity flow function $\psi(r,t)$ that could be derived by (1) establishing the relation between two vortex area functions, $a(t)$ and $A(r)$, using the disk method of integration, and (2) making the assumption of rotation equilibrium, $ω+dω=0$. Is this assumption about the angular velocity tending towards zero as the radius, $R(t)$, tends to infinity, reasonable, given that,
$$ \delta \Gamma = \delta A \left ( 2\omega \right )$$
$$ \sum \omega \propto \frac{1}{\sum R} \therefore \propto \frac{1}{\sum a}, \forall t$$
$$  \displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty }\sum 2\omega =0 $$
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty } \left ( 2\omega +2d\omega \right ) = 0$$
$$  2\omega + 2d\omega = 0 $$
$$\frac{d\Gamma }{dA} + \frac{\Gamma }{a}=0$$
$$ \frac{d\Gamma }{dA} =- \frac{\Gamma }{a} $$
where, $\omega$ is the angular velocity, $R$ is the radius at a certain time, $t$, $\Gamma$ is circulation, and $a$ is likewise, $a(t)=\pi R(t)^2$? The relation between $dA=2\pi rdr$ and $a(t)=\pi R^2$ from the disk method is,
$$ \int \int dV=\int _{T_1}^{T_2}\int _0^{R\left(t\right)}2\pi \:rdrdt $$
$$ \int dV=\int _{T_1}^{T_2}\pi R\left(t\right)^2dt=\int _{T_1}^{T_2}a\left(t\right)dt $$
$$ \frac{dV}{dt}=a\left(t\right)=dA $$
The derivation is 7 pages long, so here is just the final flow function in a vector field in cylindrical coordinates $ \vec{v}=\left< 0, v_\theta , 0 \right>$ along with the graph in desmos 3D:
$$\psi \left(r,t \right)=\frac{w_{0}R_{0}^{2}}{R(t)^{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{r^2}{R(t)^{2}}\right)}$$
$$v_\theta = r\sqrt{e}\psi (r,t) = r\sqrt{e}\frac{w_{0}R_{0}^{2}}{R(t)^{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{r^2}{R(t)^{2}}\right)}$$

Ignore, $(b,d)=(0,0)$.

